# Prevent javascript execution in IE6

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6, cross-browser

I want to prevent some parts of my javascript, written with jQuery if that matters, from executing in IE6. What are the prefered methods to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: May I ask why would you want to do this?

Comment: I am doing some fancy javascript stuff that is not supported by <=IE6 so for visitors using those browsers I want to serve the fully functional page without the javascript enhancements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use conditional comments to define a variable, and check if it's set on execution.

The syntax is `<!--[if IE 6> <script ... /><![endif]-->`. The content of the comment is invisible to all other browsers, so it's really foolproof.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have mentioned JQuery, why don't you use " `if ($.browser.msie`)" construction. I think this [resource](http://api.jquery.com) will be useful for you

Answer (score 0):

For your stated purpose, you should definitely use [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) instead of browser detection.

Comment: The browser object is deprecated in jQuery 1.3+.

Answer (score 0):

You should just use a browser detection script and put a condition on IE6 that your scripts should not be executed. here is a link for [browser detection](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html) javascript.